# Difference between multi layer chip inductor and high frequency chip inductor

Tags: inductor, high-frequency

What is the difference between a multi-layer chip inductor and a high-frequency chip inductor? 
And also what is the difference between rated current and saturation current if an inductor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rated Current** is the maximum continuous current that the inductor can withstand. Generally the limiting factor for this parameter is the temperature rise of the inductor.

**Saturation Current** is the current value in which inductor core saturation occurs. This happens  because there is a limit to the level of magnetic flux a magnetic core such as ferrite can take. When saturation occurs
the relative permeability falls and in turn this causes the level of inductance falls. The saturation current is generally taken to be the current at which the level of inductance falls by a specified amount - usually by 10%-20%.

There is no specific difference between the two inductors You mentioned. In fact it is possible to combine two and have high frequency multi-layer chip inductor.

As the name says **High Frequency** inductors are inductors that are made to work at high frequencies. The manufacturer is usually trying to obtain a good benefactor by reducing capacitance and parasitic resistance.

**Multilayer** means that the inductor is constructed as a stackup of multiple layers of conductive trace separated by ferrite material. The other popular type of chip inductor construction is wire chip inductor.

Multilayer chip inductor:

[image]

Wire chip inductor:

[image]